# Is there a Java program snippet which can compile with a Java 5 compiler on JRE 6 but not Java 6 compiler?

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-construction

I want to have a source file which can compile with javac / ecj set to Java 5 but not Java 6 (even if the underlying Java runtime is Java 6).

This is to be certain that the compiler level is set correctly in Eclipse 3.5 running with Java 6 installed, but where the result needs to run on a Java 5 installation.

For java 1.4 I could use "enum" as a variable name (which fails under Java 5 and later) but I cannot locate a similar approach for Java 5 versus 6 (and later).

Suggestions?

Comment: why dont u just change the compiler level on eclipse??

Comment: @Diago, from the question "This is to be certain that the compiler level is set correctly".

Comment: There's nothing in the language that was removed between JDK5 and 6. The only thing which was added, as has been said, was the override annotation on interface methods - hence not a keyword. Hence you're stuck with library diferences, I'm afraid

Comment: Note:  When using maven modern IDE's can choose the most appropriate Java distribution amongst those provided to it based on the meta data in pom.xml making this much less of a problem.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's nothing in *the Java language* that was *removed* between JDK5 and 6. The only thing which was added, as has been said, was the `@Override` annotation being allowable on interface methods - no keywords. Hence you are left with library diferences as the only cause of breaking changes, I'm afraid.

These do exist, even in the core API; in an unusual fit of backwards-compatibility-breaking revelry they changed the signature of some methods on the `ExecutorService` interface. This was because the generic signatures of the methods were overly restrictive. This was a *pure library change* (although, being part of `java.util`, a pretty **core library**); nothing to do with any language-level modification.

For example, [from JDK5](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) :

```
<T> T invokeAny(Collection<Callable<T>> tasks)
```

[to JDK6](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html):

```
<T> T invokeAny(Collection<? extends Callable<T>> tasks)
```

This means that any program which contained code *implementing* this interface in JDK5, would not have compiled against JDK6. A snippet is easy to create; just let your IDE create an empty implementation of the JDK5 interface and then build against JDK6.

**Note:** that the wildcard was added because the previous version would not have accepted a parameter like `List<MyCallable<String>>` (i.e. the collection being typed by some subclass of callable) whereas the later version does.

Comment: Good catch. +1 (illustrated here http://old.nabble.com/Incompatible-API-change-between-Java-5-and-Java-6--td22983799.html)

Comment: I can attest to having been bitten by this - now we have to support two versions of some of our code, purely because of this library change

Answer (score 2):

Since [JVMDI](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/jpda/jvmdi-spec.html) was removed and JVMPI was disabled in Java SE 6 (according to [J2SE 6.0 release note](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/webnotes/compatibility.html#source)), you could add a code using that API: it will not compile with J2SE 6.0, only 5.0. (as illustrated by [this thread](http://dev.eclipse.org/newslists/news.eclipse.newcomer/msg16185.html))

Comment: If I understand you correctly, this is a JRE difference, not a language change?   So it will be dependent on the JRE used, not the compiler level?  I do not want to use Java 5 while developing, just catch that the compiler level is incorrect.

Comment: @Thorbjørn: yes, I cannot find any actual code which could be compiled, only dynamic library loaded at runtime. So, for now, it is not an appropriate solution (I keep it in CW mode for archive)

Answer (score 0):

Not an answer to your question but an alternative to your approach: wouldn't it be possible to use a second builder, based on ant or maven, that you use on demand to create the final application or library? This build would use a real external Java 5 SDK and thus guarantee that the application/library runs in a Java5 environment.

Comment: Yes.  We have a build system, which builds artifacts on the right level etc.  It takes time, however, and during development I often have to build with Eclipse on my PC and run on the development machine (which only has Java 5, not a PC).  Hence, the need to be certain to use Java 5.  We very frequently create new workspaces, as the Working Set facility in Eclipse is a joke.

Comment: Fully agree on Working Set feature. One workspace/project is what I'm doing too ;)